# IDataErrorInfo re-attaches in combination with MVVM Light messaging

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, idataerrorinfo

For a project I'm working on I use IDataErrorInfo for validation on user input. I'm also using MVVM light messaging. But it seems that the error handling is re-attached on every ShowDialog what causes the validation to happen multiple times, and stacking up every time the dialog is shown. The ViewModel is kept during open/close and not re-created.

**View (textbox)**

```
<TextBox Name="LPNInput" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,40,10,10"
         Text="{Binding Path=LPN, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
         extensions:FocusExtension.IsFocused="True">
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LpnValidationErrorTemplate}" />
   </Style>
 </TextBox.Style>
 <TextBox.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=SubmitLPNCommand}" Key="Enter" />
 </TextBox.InputBindings>   
</TextBox>
```

**ViewModel RequestInputViewModel**

```
private string lpn;
public string LPN
{
    get { return lpn; }
    set
    {
        lpn = value; RaisePropertyChanged("LPN");
    }
}

public string Error { get; private set; }
public string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        string errorMsg = string.Empty;
        if (propertyName.Equals("LPN"))
        {
            pannenkoek++;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lpn))
            {
                if (!LicensePlateNumber.IsValidLPN(lpn))
                {
                    errorMsg = XmlTextProvider.GetHeader("LPNInvalid");
                }
                else if (!someManager.CanAddBag(LicensePlateNumber.Parse(lpn)))
                {
                    errorMsg = XmlTextProvider.GetHeader("LPNDuplicate");
                }
            }
        }

        Error = errorMsg;
        return Error;
    }
}

private void Close(bool dialogResult)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Pannenkoeken: {0}", pannenkoek));

    // Notify the view to close the dialog
    Messenger.Default.Send<CloseWindowMessage, RequestInputDialog>(new CloseWindowMessage(this, dialogResult));
}
```

**ViewModel #2**

RequestLPNViewModel is created in the constructor of viewmodel #2.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Messenger.Default.Send<ShowDialogMessageBase, MainView>(new ShowDialogMessage<RequestInputDialog>(this, RequestInputViewModel, InputEntered))));
```

**Output in debug output**

Pannenkoeken: 2
Pannenkoeken: 4
Pannenkoeken: 6
Pannenkoeken: 8

I wouldn't expect the increase in numbers. I would have expect 4x the number 2. It seems that the error binding is attached on creation of the dialog, but not released when the dialog is closed. And yes, the int is reset on open :)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the dialog behavior I've chosen to recreate the viewmodel every time the dialog is created. Perhaps also better to do to prevent any future 'weird' behavior with old/previous data.

The viewmodel isn't representing any state this way.